# Why my camera is not opening after clicking?

Tags: android, kotlin

My Camera is not opening here is the code.

```
profile_image.setOnClickListener {
        openMediaBottomSheet(true)
    }
```

Bottom sheet method here

```
fun openMediaBottomSheet(isDelete: Boolean) {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.up_select_media_dialog,
            null
        )
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this!!, R.style.SheetDialog)
        view.txt_select_media_.text = getString(R.string.select_media_)
        view.txt_camera.text = getString(R.string.camera)
        view.txt_gallery.text = getString(R.string.gallery)
        view.txt_take_a_.text = getString(R.string.use_a_)

        view.card_camera.setOnClickListener {
            if (Constants.isPermissionGranted(this!!, requiredPermissions)) {
                (this).dispatchTakePictureIntent()
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this!!,
                    requiredPermissions,
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
                )
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        //                  view.txt_remove_pic.setOnClickListener {
        //                      val bodyMap = java.util.HashMap<String, Any>().apply {
        //                          put("id", userId)
        //                          put("profileImage", "")
        //                          put("profileImageThumb", "")
        //                      }
        //                      userUpdateViewModel.updateUserData(bodyMap)
        //                      dialog.dismiss()
        //                  }

        view.card_gallery_up.setOnClickListener {
            MyPreferences.saveIntInPreference(this!!, "maxSelect", 1)
            InsGallery.openGalleryForImages(
                this, GlideEngine.createGlideEngine(),
                GlideCacheEngine.createCacheEngine(), ArrayList<LocalMedia>(),
                PictureConfig.REQUEST_GALLERY_IMAGE_FOR_POST
            )
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        dialog.setContentView(view)
        dialog.show()
    }
```

also, permission is assigned

```
        private val requiredPermissions = arrayOf("android.permission.CAMERA")
```

Comment: where is the code to open camera.

Answer (score 0):

Package visibility is restricted in Android 11(API 30) and above. https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility. So, the `resolveActivity()` method returns `null`. Adding the following to your AndroidManifest.xml lets your app query the required package.

```
<manifest>
...
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```